# Sort JSON array after $.getJSON excecuted

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting, getjson

I have a working connection between my json object and getJSON(). I can also sort the data i get once with this code, I sorted it on the 'name' field of the array and it works fine:

```
$.getJSON(url,function(json){ 
    function sortJson(a,b){
        return a.name > b.name? 1 : -1;
    }
    json.users.sort(sortJson);  
    $.each(json.users,function(i,row){ 
        $("#output").append(
            '<li>' + row.id + row.name + row.job + '</li>'
        );
    }); 
});
```

and this is my json array:

```
{"users":[
{"id":"1","name":"John","job":"worker"}
{"id":"2","name":"Mike","job":"innovator"}
{"id":"3","name":"Anna","job":"reader"}
]}
```

What I want is that when i click on a button the sortJson() should sort the users on another field like 'id' or 'job'. I did this:

```
function sortJsonField(x){
    var field = x;
    var url="http://localhost/api/users.php";
    $.getJSON(url,function(json){ 
        function sortJson(a,b){
            if(field == "id"){ return a.id > b.id? 1 : -1; }else
            if(field == "job"){ return a.job > b.job? 1 : -1; }else
            return a.name > b.name? 1 : -1;
        }
        json.users.sort(sortJson);  
        $.each(json.users,function(i,row){ 
            $("#output").append(
                '<li>' + row.id + row.name + row.job + '</li>'
            );
        }); 
    });
}
```

and it worked, now you should be wondering what my problem is. Here it is, every time I click on the button to execute *sortJsonField('thefieldname')*. It executes the whole $.getJSON, making a new connection with the url and communicating with the back-end. I don't want that, it's too slow and the workload will be heavy for the server.
I want to get the json once and then sort the array afterwards(so actually only the $.each function i need to refresh). But it's not working.

Any ideas?

**okay i modified the code and i think i'm really close:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><head>
<title>Users</title>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url="http://192.168.247.86/X/users.php";
    var json =  { users: [] };
    //getting & storing
    $.getJSON(url,function(response){
        json = response;    
    });
    //sorting
    function sortJsonField(field){
        alert(field);
        function sortJson(a,b){
            if(field == "id"){ return a.id > b.id? 1 : -1; }else
            if(field == "job"){ return a.job > b.job? 1 : -1; }else
            return a.name > b.name? 1 : -1;
        }

        json.users.sort(sortJson);
        showJSON();
    };
    //showing
    function showJSON(){
        $.each(json.users,function(i,row){ 
            $("#output").append(
                '<li><em>' + row.id + '</em><br>' + row.name + '<br>' + row.job  + '</li>'
            );
        });
    };
});
</script>
</head>

<h1>Users</h1>
<button onClick="sortJsonField(Id)">Id</button>
<button onClick="sortJsonField('Name')">Name</button>
<button onClick="sortJsonField('Job')">Job</button>
<ul id="output"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my json:

```
{"users":[{"id":"1","name":"John","job":"Worker"},{"id":"2","name":"Mike","job":"Reader"},{"id":"3","name":"Mary","job":"Writer"},{"id":"4","name":"Angelo","job":"Player"},{"id":"5","name":"Kevin","job":"Doctor"},{"id":"6","name":"Zidane","job":"Player"}]}
```

**Got it working now**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url="http://localhost/X/users.php";
    var json = new Array();
    //getter
    $.getJSON(url,function(data){
        json = data;
    }).done(function(){
        sortJsonField();
        $('#sortid').click(function(){
            sortJsonField("id");
        })
        $('#sortname').click(function(){
            sortJsonField("name");
        })
        $('#sortjob').click(function(){
            sortJsonField("job");
        })
    });

        function sortJsonField(field){
            function sortJson(a,b){
                if(field == "id"){ return a.id > b.id? 1 : -1; }else
                if(field == "job"){ return a.job > b.job? 1 : -1; }else
                return a.name > b.name? 1 : -1;
            }
            json.users.sort(sortJson);
            showJSON();
        };
        //shower
        function showJSON(){
            $('#output').empty();
            $.each(json.users,function(i,row){ 
                $("#output").append(
                    '<li><em>' + row.id + '</em><br>' + row.name + '<br>' + row.job + '</li>'
                );
            });
        };
        showJSON(); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="sortid">Id</button>
<button id="sortname">Name</button>
<button id="sortjob">Job</button>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you should keep the data in an intermediate way. This *storage* should be the base for the diplayed data and your sorting function only works on that storage. The load function is only called to update that storage. But without a glimps at your html, it's a bit hard to give a more concrete example.

Comment: I think i understand. the data i get from $.getJSON should be stored in an array and i should display and sort that array and not the retrieved data directly. Is that what you mean? btw my html only has an <ul> for the data and some script source references.

Comment: Yes, pretty much. See @Abimbola s answer for one way to do it, though I'd advice against using global variables. Also if you're planing to implement a lot of such functionality have a look at established [frameworks](https://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/04/12/comparison-angular-backbone-can-ember/), for jQuery really issn't the best option here.

Comment: I'm still learning the main functionalities. I might look into frameworks later on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
var json = { users: [] };
var url="http://localhost/api/users.php";
$.getJSON(url,function(response){
    json = response;
});

function sortJsonField(field){

    function sortJson(a,b){
        if(field == "id"){ return a.id > b.id? 1 : -1; }else
        if(field == "job"){ return a.job > b.job? 1 : -1; }else
        return a.name > b.name? 1 : -1;
    }

    // No need to assign this to a new array.
    json.users.sort(sortJson);

    showJSON();
};

function showJSON(){

    // May empty the ul/ol before doing this? up to you..
    $.each(json.users,function(i,row){ 
        $("#output").append(
            '<li>' + row.id + row.name + row.job + '</li>'
        );
    });

};
```

**EDIT:** Also, the JSON structure is slightly incorrect...

Change this:

```
{"users":[
{"id":"1","name":"John","job":"worker"}
{"id":"2","name":"Mike","job":"innovator"}
{"id":"3","name":"Anna","job":"reader"}
]}
```

....to this:

```
{"users":[
{"id":"1","name":"John","job":"worker"},     // <--- Do you see the commas here?
{"id":"2","name":"Mike","job":"innovator"},    // <--- and here?
{"id":"3","name":"Anna","job":"reader"}
]}
```

The objects are well-formed, but that is not a valid array, so javascript breaks. Modify it and it should all work.

**P.S** This is the url of the website I used to check your JSON structure: http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html

Comment: okay, tested this completely and everything works except the `json = response`. when i manually write the json array values into 'json' it works(ex var json = { users: [ {'name':'as',etc etc etc} ] }). the $.getjson part is not putting the retrieved values, i checked the connection, it's connected. Any fix for it mate?

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your JSON response from the server, exactly as it appears? I can tell you what's wrong based on that

Comment: This is exactly what i have: `{"users":[{"id":"1","name":"John","job":"Worker"},{"id":"2","name":"Mike","job":"Reader"},{"id":"3","name":"Mary","job":"Writer"},{"id":"4","name":"Angelo","job":"Player"},{"id":"5","name":"Kevin","job":"Doctor"},{"id":"6","name":"Zidane","job":"Player"}]}`

Comment: Based on the structure you posted, this should work perfectly fine. The only case where it would break is if you called the `sortJsonField()` function **before** the `$.getJSON()` call returns. Check to see if that's the problem, or post a jsFiddle

Comment: Yeah I checked it and the code looks good. But it just doesn't store the array. When i manually add the array values it works(only shows, no sort). The other issue is how i should invoke the sort function. When i put the `$('#sortid').click(sortJsonField('id'))` for example it works when the page loads instead of when clicking on the #sortid element. I'm searching for json to array alternatives now. And also the function firing.

Comment: The thing about ajax is that is it 'asynchronous' in nature.. if you trigger the `$('#sortid').click(sortJsonField('id'))` handler before the page is fully loaded, the variable `json` will still be set to the default value of `var json = { users: [] };`. There is no way of avoiding that, that is how AJAX (**Asynchronous Javascript and XML**) works.

You're best option is to only enable the click function on `$('#sortid')` **after** the `$.getJSON()` function is return a response. It will always work if you do that

Comment: abimdola, i checked it again. I got the function triggering working now. The only thing that needs fixing now is the json to array. The `json = response` is not working. I tried .stringify .parse nothing damn puts the json in the array. Any help?

Comment: Hi Harv, just got home....is there any way I can test your code with live data? Can you post a jsFiddle or something, I don't mind have a look at the data

Comment: One more info, when i output response, it shows me the correct retrieved json object. The problem is i declared the json array outside of the getJson function and when i do `json = response` it's only in the getJson function. Not public

Comment: You can remove the 'var' infront of json to make it a global variable.

Comment: Hey...I figured out what is wrong with your JSON. I will add the solution to my previous answer in a minute

Comment: The json is validated, the only problem now is that the $.getJson function doesn't save the global array 'json'. It adds the retrieved data, but outside of that function it disappears again.

Comment: Hey don't worry, i got it now. The thing was, the $.each executed after the other functions, i changed the code with a .done

Comment: Good. Don't forget to close this by accepting an answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a variable that will store the JSON and use that once the request returns.

```
var jsonData;
$.getJSON(url,function(json){ 
      jsonData = json;
});
```

Now you can sort the data contained in `jsonData`.

Comment: Yeah I got this one, but the jsonData = json is the issue now. Not working, i will google some alternatives of storing a json in an array