# Javascript and JQuery synchronous execute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which append some elements if a json file was loaded:

```
function loadNdraw(title, id){

    $("#containerCharts").html("");

    var date = $("#dateChart");

    var jqJSON = $.getJSON("charts/" + id + "/" + date.val() + ".json");

    jqJSON.done(

        function(data){

            $("#containerCharts").append(
                "<div class='divStandard'>"
                    + "<div class='titleChart'>"
                        + "<div style='float: left;'>" + title + "</div>"
                        + "<div style='float: right;'>" + data.lastUpdate +"</div>"
                        + "<div style='clear: both;'></div>"
                    + "</div>"
                    + "<center><div id='" + id + "' class='bodyChart'></div></center>"
                + "</div>"
            );

        }

    );

}
```

I call this function multiple times

```
loadNdraw("A", "a");
loadNdraw("B", "b");
loadNdraw("C", "c");
loadNdraw("D", "d");
```

My problem is that it does not load in this order.

Every time the page is loaded, the order of A,B,C,D is random.

How can I force it to be loaded in order?

I don't want to sort json.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort JSON array after $.getJSON excecuted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391515/sort-json-array-after-getjson-excecuted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.promise()` function in jquery

```
function loadNdraw(title, id){

    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();

    $("#containerCharts").html("");

    var date = $("#dateChart");

    var jqJSON = $.getJSON("charts/" + id + "/" + date.val() + ".json");

    jqJSON.done(

        function(data){

            $("#containerCharts").append(
                "<div class='divStandard'>"
                    + "<div class='titleChart'>"
                        + "<div style='float: left;'>" + title + "</div>"
                        + "<div style='float: right;'>" + data.lastUpdate +"</div>"
                        + "<div style='clear: both;'></div>"
                    + "</div>"
                    + "<center><div id='" + id + "' class='bodyChart'></div></center>"
                + "</div>"
            );

        }

    );

    dfd.resolve(true);

}
```

Then you can simply call

```
$.when( loadNdraw("A", "a") ).then(
  $.when( loadNdraw("B", "b") ).then(
  //Some code 
  );
);
```

You can simply use `.promise` as per your need

Answer (score 2):

The JSON scripts are being loaded asynchronously. The order in which the callbacks fire don't depend on the order in which you invoke `loadNdraw`, but the order in which `jqJSON.done` gets fired. The file that loads the fastest will cause its `jqJSON.done` method to be called first, and so on.

If you need these to be in order, you have a few options:

1. Sort the HTML structure after all results have loaded (or each time a file loads)
2. Load the charts sequentially, by calling `loadNdraw` inside of `jqJSON.done`, meaning that chart `B` would only start loading after `A` is done—this is likely to be much slower.
3. Populate the results in a temporary data structure, keep track of [`when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) all requests have completed, and then handle the DOM manipulation based on that data.

Option 3 seems to be your best bet in this situation:

```
function loadNdraw(title, id) {
    $("#containerCharts").html("");

    var date = $("#dateChart");
    return $.getJSON("charts/" + id + "/" + date.val() + ".json");
}

var options = [
    { title: 'A', id: 'a' },
    { title: 'B', id: 'b' },
    { title: 'C', id: 'c' },
    { title: 'D', id: 'd' }
];

for (var option of options) {
    option.promise = loadNdraw(option.title, option.id);
}

$.when(...options.map(o => o.promise)).done(function(...results) {
    results.forEach(function(dataArray, idx) {
        var title = options[idx].title;
        var id = options[idx].id;

        $("#containerCharts").append(
            "<div class='divStandard'>"
                + "<div class='titleChart'>"
                    + "<div style='float: left;'>" + title + "</div>"
                    + "<div style='float: right;'>" + dataArray[0].lastUpdate +"</div>"
                    + "<div style='clear: both;'></div>"
                + "</div>"
                + "<center><div id='" + id + "' class='bodyChart'></div></center>"
            + "</div>"
        );
    });
});
```

Note a couple of things here:

1. The argument to [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) is a listing of of [*Thenables*](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Thenable)—objects like your jqXHR with a `then` method. You can pass it an array objects by expanding it with the [`...spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator.
2. The callback for [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) takes a listing of response objects as its parameter, in the order in which the requests were made. They can be collected into an array using the [`...rest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) parameter syntax.