# Sorting the table data using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to sort the table data as alphabetical order. The HTML needs not to be reloaded again.
The JSON data hosted on an online server, The button can be added when clicking the table should be sorted automatically with the column "title" alphabetically.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("my json file", function(data) {
    var movie_data = '';
    $.each(data.movies, function(key, value) {
      movie_data += '<tr>';
      movie_data += '<td>' + value.title + '</td>';
      movie_data += '<td>' + value['imdb-id'] + '</td>';
      movie_data += '<td>' + value.rank + '</td>';
      movie_data += '<td>' + value.rating + '</td>';
      movie_data += '<td>' + value['rating-count'] + '</td>';
      movie_data += '<tr>';
    });
    $('#movie_table').append(movie_data);
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>JSON data to HTML table</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <h1>TOP MOVIES</h1>

      <br />
      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="movie_table">
        <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>IMDB-ID</th>
          <th>RANK</th>
          <th>RATING</th>
          <th>RATING-COUNT</th>

        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the part you are having trouble with?

Comment: Check this it's same use case than your, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391515/sort-json-array-after-getjson-excecuted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort JSON array after $.getJSON excecuted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391515/sort-json-array-after-getjson-excecuted)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = null;
  $.getJSON("my json file", function(jsonData) {
    data = jsonData.movies;
    reloadTable();
  });

  $("#btn-sort").click(function() {
    data.sort(function(a,b) {
      return a.title < b.title ? -1 : 1;
    });
    reloadTable();
  });
  
  function reloadTable() {
    var movie_data = '';
    $.each(data.movies, function(key, value) {
      movie_data += '<tr>';
      movie_data += '<td>' + value.title + '</td>';
      movie_data += '<td>' + value['imdb-id'] + '</td>';
      movie_data += '<td>' + value.rank + '</td>';
      movie_data += '<td>' + value.rating + '</td>';
      movie_data += '<td>' + value['rating-count'] + '</td>';
      movie_data += '<tr>';
    });
    $('#movie_table').slice(1).remove(); // To remove everything except first row
    $('#movie_table').append(movie_data);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>JSON data to HTML table</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <h1>TOP MOVIES</h1>
      <button id="btn-sort">Sort</button>
      <br />
      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="movie_table">
        <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>IMDB-ID</th>
          <th>RANK</th>
          <th>RATING</th>
          <th>RATING-COUNT</th>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, i got a problem data.sort is not a function.

Comment: My bad, there was a bug in the `getJSON()` function. I've edited the answer. Please try now.